# Adobe CQ CDN integration

Tags: cdn, aem

I am using AEM 5.6 and trying to integrate it with CDN. I was going thru web on this but could not found much apart from http://cq-ops.tumblr.com/post/110829806684/how-to-integrate-aem-with-a-cdn-such-as-akamai

From where i can start as a newbie?What are standards & best practices for same? How CDN cache works & how it is invalidated?Also what are CDN cache invalidation mechanism which can be used?

Comment: You need to look at your CDN's documentation. If you're paying for Akamai or CloudFlare, they will have docs on how to integrate with your site. It generally doesn't matter that you're using AEM/CQ from the CDN's perspective. As that blog post states, there is no automatic invalidation available. You can either roll your own or just use a TTL (time-to-live) for expiration.

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate Akamai with Author as well as dispatcher URL. But since author contents are manly dynamic, you do not want to cache them in Akamai. You can use Akamai only to safeguard as a firewall. But in case of dispatcher URL/live URL you can cache all the static contents in akamai. TTL is configurable in the  configurations in there portal.

Comment: Thanks a lot, can i get some official documentation for same?

Comment: Official documentations are available in Akamai portal. I suggest you to talk to a akamai representative.